# Ant build and deploy application is OK, how to debug application?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant

Ant help us to build and deploy applications, but how to debug application in the Application server?

Could you please help me to debug the EAR file created with Ant build?

(I have imported the EAR file in to Eclipse to debug using Eclipse, I am able to run the project successfully, but when I start debug after setting a breakpoint it reports as Source not found, please help me to resolve this issue)

Comment: When you debug your application, you should have your project (source code) open in the IDE. Personally I use Netbeans, and I will open the project, start the application individualy with JPDA arguments, and connect to the remote debugger from Netbeans using socket (ip+port).

Answer (score 1):

You have to not only "import" your EAR file (containing compiled bytecode) but also your source code files. If you import the EAR as a "referenced library" you may edit the library with alt-enter, and add the path/jar of the sources.

How do you start & publish in eclipse anyways?